# Windows 10 driver installation issue

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers

I have a Oneplus 3, and after I updated my laptop's Windows 10 to the new Anniversary Update (I'm not sure what's the reason, so I mentioned this, just in case), it fails to recognize the MTP option when I connect the phone to my laptop. Although, it is able to recognize the phone in P2P (Photo Transfer) mode and wholly recognizable on my Ubuntu on the same laptop and other Windows laptops/PCs apart from mine.

I tried updating the driver software from the Device Manager but it shows the following error:

```
Windows found driver software for your device but encountered an error while attempting
to install it.
[MTP Device Symbol]
A service installation section in this INF is invalid.
```

I'm not sure what to do now, I saw some solutions to this, but all of them dated back to Win XP and use of something called as **user driver framework**.

Thank you.

Comment: You will have to identify the error in the INF my guess it has a static version check on Windows

Comment: @Ramhound Can you explain how should I do that?